# Point projection in GeoPandas for OSMnx graph

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, osmnx

I am struggling with a crs conversion in GeoPandas.
Basically I just want to calculate the distance between a point and an edge of my OSMnx graph.
The coordinates of the point are retrieved from the mapillary API and should be in WGS84 crs ("our spatial data uses WGS84" [[Ref]](https://blog.mapillary.com/product/2017/04/12/how-to-retrieve-mapillary-images-to-use-in-external-tools.html))

Here is my Code

```
import osmnx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

G = ox.graph_from_bbox(**my_bbox)
P = ox.project_graph(G)
point = gpd.GeoSeries(Point(9.81, 40.06), crs="WGS84")
point_p = point.to_crs(P.graph['crs'])
_, dist = ox.nearest_edges(P, point_p.x, point_p.y, return_dist=True)
print(dist)
```

> Output: 967443.035158215

Unfortunately, the calculated value is by far too big.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't tell what is wrong with the code above, however I did manage to find a way to convert the point correctly now (which in addition works without GeoPandas)

```
import osmnx as ox
from shapely.geometry import Point

G = ox.graph_from_bbox(**my_bbox)
P = ox.project_graph(G)
point = (lng, lat) # 
point_geom_proj, crs = ox.projection.project_geometry(
        Point(point), to_crs=P.graph['crs']
    ) #point_geom_proj is a WGS84 Point with UTM projection
```